# Multiple audio player not showing in top panel

Tags: panel, music, gnome-shell-extension

I always keep my playlist running in the **YouTube music or Spotify** and the song name and controls appear in the top panel when I'm working. But when I play a **YouTube video** in my browser, the player controls will change to the video that I'm playing right now.

The problem comes when I play the video and want to pause the music, I have to go to the respective source and not from the top panel since it is not showing anywhere. It will get changed once I open the music app window. Is there any way to show those multiple audio player sources in the top panel?

[image: top_panel-screenshot]

I have tried several extensions to achieve this but failed.

**UPDATE:** I just found that it happens when I use multiple audio sources within the same browser. I have to use the browser since there is no YouTube or YouTube Music software in the App Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the audio source is from a **single application** (in my case the browser, even though I have installed the web app). Currently, Ubuntu is unable to detect different audio sources coming from only one application.

We can try the same by installing the **Spotify** or normal **Ubuntu audio player** and will find multiple sources listed in the top panel.